# I want to send the user a notification whenever a new child is added to a node in my firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, apple-push-notifications

I want to find the equivalent of a service in android to listen for changes in the node so it sends a notification to the user whenever a child is added.

Comment: Do you mean push notification? and what is the purpose of this, is this for a real time chat?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to use one signal to send a notification to a user whenever a new chat message is added.

Comment: This kind of notifications shouldn't be triggered by the clients. Use Firebase Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to enable the pushNotification in the device capability and then create a push notification certificate. Then add this certificate to the firebase cloud messaging. Then from the firebase SDK you need to create a device token. To this token, firebase is pushing the notification. When you insert a new message you need to call a firebase push notification api with the of receiver's device token.